# When Moving XR Rig it move the main camera far from XR Origin Position

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, virtual-reality, unity3d-editor

When I move XR origin in scene  X and Z position, it move the main camera far away, any Idea how I can solve this

I try the Main camera out then move XR origin, then drag the main camera in and reset the position, but this seem to not move the XR Rig at all. I try to move the XR Rig while no Main camera inside then recreate the Main camera again ,but when I recreate it calculate XR Rig Old position and add addition position to the Main camera.

Note: This is happened while Moving XR origin in scene and not in code ,plus the editor was not in play mode

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Play the Editor and move the XR Origin ,Select the XR Origin go to the Inspector < Transform, click three dot copy world Position and not position ,then Stop playing .
Select XR Origin < Inspector < Transform ,paste a World position.

Note: When play the editor and moving XR origin the camera don't add additional position relative to its parent .This how you can move the XR origin without moving the camera relative to its parent.

Note: When the Editor is not played the XR Origin will be placed far from the camera ,but don't worry when you play ,it will return to the Original position you placed it.

Answer (score 0):

The Most Correct Answer is this, go to the Unity Editor < Scene, go to **Toggle Tool handle Position**, click the drop-down option, and choose Pivot.